# Method for identifying upstream segments

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.0, vector, line, strahler

I need to add to the attribute table of a stream network layer a column that can identify all upstream segments that contribute to the segment (for each segment).

My best idea at the moment is to assign all stream segments with a Strahler order of 1 a prime number.  Then going downstream, I multiply the contributing upstream segments (see graphic below).  From this, I think I can factorise the number into it's primes and then work out the IDs of all upstream segments.

I already have a script that is capable of passing information downstream based on the Strahler stream order so this is not a problem.  I just want to know what a better method would be, my method is going to generate horribly large numbers once I start processing large stream networks!

As an example, in the graphic below, if i was to look at the segment with the 210 attribute, I would factorise this into primes of 2,3,5 and 7.  From these primes I could work out that 6 and 35 were also upstream segements.

I have access to ArcGIS basic 10.2.2 and QGiS.
[image]

Comment: I've always had better success going up a network instead of down, but that was for stream turning. I used a recursive routine using the opposite end as a selection point. Yes it consumes a lot of memory for a large stream network but worked without crashing. What language is the script? do you have ArcObjects experience?

Comment: Hi,  the script is in Python, since we do not have spatial analyst it uses Saga or Grass modules to delineate stream networks and catchments.  No experience in ArcObjects but then I didn't have any experience in the SDK for ArcGIS till a couple of weeks ago!  Keen to learn if it could help me.

Comment: It's a big task, but a journey of a thousand miles still begins with one step. Do you have a programming language in mind? I think VB is the easiest to start from. Generally speaking the SDK for ArcGis *is* ArcObjects, the separation between them was resolved at about 8.3 now they're synonyms.

Comment: I would be using VB, more familiar with VB than C#

Comment: That's diverging from the original question. May I recommend posting a question on 'how to get started in VB ArcObjects' which can be addressed there, by myself and other great people, and then come back to this post after getting some ArcObjects initialization. Hint: VB express is free for non-commercial applications, but the right version can be a bit hard to find. If you are programming in v10.x I would recommend visual studio express 2010.